# Read Table of contents using vba

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

I am trying to read a table of contents in a word document without reading the page numbers. I want to read the table and save it into an array. Coding is not my strong suit so apologies in advance if this question is directed to the wrong area. I have the following piece of code which I found inline, which reads the table and the page numbers but I can't work out how to just read the table.

```
Dim sourceDocument As Document
Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument

Dim myField As Field
For Each myField In sourceDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Range.Fields
    Debug.Print myField.result.Text ', Chr(13), "-") & " " & " Type: " & myField.Type

   DoEvents
Next
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,

Robbie

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on your way:

```
Public Function GetTOCItems(Optional ByVal fromDocument As Document = Nothing) As Variant

    If fromDocument Is Nothing Then _
        Set fromDocument = ActiveDocument

    Dim toc As TableOfContents
    Set toc = fromDocument.TablesOfContents(1)

    toc.IncludePageNumbers = False

    Dim tocText As Variant
    tocText = toc.Range.Text

    toc.IncludePageNumbers = True

    GetTOCItems = Split(tocText, Chr(13))

End Function
```

And you can call it like this:

```
Dim tocItems as Variant
tocItems = GetTOCItems
```

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me, I really appreciate the help. I will try this tomorrow morning when I'm at my desktop and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi,  I just wanted to let you know that your suggestion worked perfectly so thank you for that.

Comment: I don't want to torment you but can I ask another question? I have the code cleaned up now and it works but I don't think it is robust enough. Basically, I want the code to read through the table of contents and then find the corresponding word documents and copy the contents under the appropriate heading. It works fine but for some documents it gets confused and wants to close the main document instead of the one it has found for the heading. I will put the code in the next comment. Thank you

Comment: That sounds like something that should be a new question rather than a comment.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I'm sorry about that. This is my first time on the site and I wasn't sure of the procedure. Do I just post this in a new question?